# How can I prevent this arbitrary text truncation in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, textfield

Below is code that populates a menu. Everything seems to work great, with no errors thrown, except for one crucial part. My `megaPages` array has the values `["HOME","BABIES","BRIDALS","MISC","WEDDINGS","ABOUT"]`, but the actual text that displays on screen (which is produced by megaPages) is like this:

[image: strange menu problems]

As you can see, some of the text is arbitrarily being truncated. I've traced the text strings as they get passed through the various functions at various stages of the menu-build, and they are always right, but somehow when each DisplayObject make it on screen, letters get ommitted (notice though that 'HOME' abd 'ABOUT' are fine). I don't even know where to start with this problem.

```
    function buildMenu() {
        var itemMCs = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < megaPages.length; i++) {
            megaPages[i] = megaPages[i].toUpperCase();
            trace(megaPages[i]); // at each iteration, traces as follows "HOME","BABIES","BRIDALS","MISC","WEDDINGS","ABOUT"
            var textMC = createText(megaPages[i]);

            var itemMC = new MovieClip();
            if (i!=0) {
                var newLink = new PlateLink();
                newLink.y = 0;
                itemMC.addChild(newLink);
            }


            var newPlate = new Plate();
            if (i==0) {
                newPlate.y = 0;
            } else {
                newPlate.y = newLink.height - 2;
            }
            newPlate.x = 0;
            newPlate.width = textMC.width + (plateMargin*2);
            itemMC.addChild(newPlate);

            if (i!=0) {
                newLink.x = (newPlate.width/2) - (newLink.width/2);
            }

            textMC.x = plateMargin;
            textMC.y = newPlate.y + .5;
            itemMC.addChild(textMC);

            itemMCs.push(itemMC);

            itemMC.x = (homeplateref.x + (homeplateref.width/2)) - (itemMC.width/2);
            if (i==0) {
                itemMC.y = homeplateref.y;
            } else {
                itemMC.y = itemMCs[i-1].y + (itemMCs[i-1].height - 6);
            }
            menuRef.addChild(itemMC);

        }

    }

    function createText(menuTitle) {

        trace(menuTitle);

        var textContainer : MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        var myFont = new Font1();

        var backText = instantText(menuTitle, 0x000000);

        backText.x = 1;
        backText.y = 1;

        var frontText = instantText(menuTitle, 0xFFFFFF);

        frontText.x = 0;
        frontText.y = 0;

        textContainer.addChild(backText);
        textContainer.addChild(frontText);
        return textContainer;
    }

    function instantText(textContent, color) {

        trace(textContent); // again, traces the right text each time it is fired

        var myFont = new Font1();
        var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        myFormat.size = 18;
        myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

        var myText:TextField = new TextField();
        myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        myText.embedFonts = true;
        myText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myText.text = textContent;
        myText.textColor = color;
        myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;           
        trace(myText.text);

        return myText;
    }
```

Comment: looks like you need to embed the font

Comment: what are `PlateLink` and `Plate`?

Comment: Plate and PlateLink are instances of the grey square, and linking chain for each bit of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed all the necessary characters for the font you're using.

**For textfields created in Flash:**
Select the TextField, and hit the 'Embed' button in the properties panel.

**For dynamically created textfields:**
When you set the font to export (`Font1` in your case) make sure to include all the characters you need.

You can choose to embed all uppercase characters, or just type in the ones you need for those specific menu items.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. These textfields are generated through AS3, and my font is exported as the class Font1(). What textfield is there in the Flash Authoring program, then, for me to do this to? And what exactly does embedding do for me?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using Flash to create the textfields. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yep that was it, I just selected 'include all character range' from Font1's properties in the library. Wow, I couyld have spent 6 more hours on this and been clueless, thank you!!!!

Comment: To save space in the SWF, Flash only includes the glyphs from the font that you specify. The embed settings tell Flash which ones you'll need.

Comment: @ColinBrogan Including all the glyphs for the font is a bit unnecessary, as fonts can be quite sizey and if you're including a lot of them, it adds up. For your example, it looks like you could get away with just uppercase (26 glyphs), or at a pinch Basic Latin (90 odd glyphs, which is good enough for the english language)

Comment: Thx dudes, I'll definately trim the excess glyphs. If I've learned anything from life, its that you gotta trim those loitering glyphs. They're always bad news.